# ocaml sqlite3 prepared statement

Tags: sqlite, ocaml, prepared-statement

I have the following insert for sqlite3 in ocaml, which works ok.

```ml
type article = { author : string; content: string }

let insert_article db (article: article) =
  let sql = Printf.sprintf "INSERT INTO blog (author, content) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" article.author article.content in
  match exec db sql with
  | Rc.OK -> ()
  | _ -> raise @@ Error "Failed to insert"
```

How can I convert this to use prepared statements?

I've tried this sort of thing, but there aren't slots for the author and content params,

```ml
let insert_article db (article: article) =
  let sql = prepare db "INSERT INTO blog (author, content) VALUES (?, ?)" article.author article.content in
  match exec db sql with
  | Rc.OK -> ()
  | _ -> raise @@ Error "Failed to insert"
```

I can't make much sense of the API type docs here:
http://mmottl.github.io/sqlite3-ocaml/api/sqlite3/Sqlite3/index.html#prepared-statements

I'm new to OCaml and more than a little confused. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems you've already answered your own question and are now just asking for opinion. You should post your update as an answer. If anyone thinks it can be done better, they'll post their own. Votes will then decide which is best.

Comment: @glennsl I'm not sure it's "the" way to do it. But yeah, fair point will do.

Comment: It doesn't have to be "the" way, that's why you can have multiple answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out how to bind the parameters in a prepared statement.

It seems pretty verbose, but it's progress nonetheless.

```
let insert_article db (article : article) =
  let stmt = prepare db "INSERT INTO blog (author, content) VALUES (?, ?)" in
  let authorBind = bind stmt 1 @@ Data.TEXT article.author in
  let contentBind = bind stmt 2 @@ Data.TEXT article.content in
  match (authorBind, contentBind) with
  | Rc.OK, Rc.OK -> (
      match step stmt with 
      | Rc.DONE -> () 
      | _ -> failwith "Failed to insert"
    )
  | _ -> failwith "Failed to bind parameters to the SQL query"
```